# Until loop in bash not working as expected

Tags: bash

The below loop is capturing two variables opt1 and opt2, however the loop exits without data being equal.

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh
       set -x


       if [ -z ${OPT1} ] || [ -z ${OPT2} ]
       then
       echo "Parameter error" 1>&2
       exit 1
       fi

       if [ $? -ne 0 ]
       then
         echo "switch logfile cannot sync correctly" 1>&2
         exit 1
       fi

   sleep 20

   echo "Check status" >> /home/oracle/scripts/log/$LOGFILE
   OPT2=`sqlplus -S username/password@${db1} << EOF
   set heading off feedback off pagesize 0 verify off echo off numwidth 15 
   select max(ARCHIVED_SEQ#) from v\\$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS;
EOF`

OPT1=`sqlplus -S username/password@${db2}<< EOF
set heading off feedback off pagesize 0 verify off echo off numwidth 15 
select max(APPLIED_SEQ#) from V\\$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS;
EOF`


if [[ !  ${OPT2} == ${OPT1} ]]
then
    echo "data do not match " 1>&2
else
    echo "data matches" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
    until [ "$OPT1" -eq "$OPT2" ]; do
    echo "data is equal." | mailx -s "DATA Match" email@mail.com
    sleep 30
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    break
    fi
    done
    echo "data match is completed" | mailx -s "DATA Match" email@mail.com
```

Please help as I expect the loop to continue until both the variables are equal and then proceed with the next commands in the script.

Comment: You check the exit code from `sleep` and if it's 0 (which it probably always is) you break out of the loop. For the `until` expression to be useful you probably want to change your variables inside the loop. Also, right now you're sending an email with "data is equal" every time `$OPT1` and `$OPT2` is **not** equal. You can try to move the `sleep` after your `if` statement to check if the email was successful. Although this still has nothing to do with `$OPT1` and `$OPT2` and will also probably be successful.

Comment: You got the logic wrong. Even https://shellcheck.net can't catch that...

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have added more details, if you can help me further.

Comment: Btw.: `bash` != `ksh`

Answer (score 1):

```
# ...
sleep 30
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
# ...
```

This checks the exit code of the `sleep` command, which is most likely not what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have added more details, if you can help me further.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can't give additional help based on additional detail of the script - because (as far as I'm convinced) the problem is that the exit code checked in the `if` line will always be the one left by the `sleep` line and therefore be identical in every try. Apparently, it is always `0`, so the break statement right under the two lines I selected will always be called after the first call to `sleep`, and the loop will *never* run more than once. If changing this fixes your problem, please `accept` the answer by hitting the checkmark. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this, use sub-shells

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function OPT1(){
  echo xx
}

function OPT2(){
  echo yy
}

# notice the use of a sub-shell instead of variables
# I am not sure about this if and what it's purpose is, do you want to fail if that sql command fails or what?
# if that's what you want, I recommend you implement that behavior in the functions that fetch the data instead of here
if [[ !  "$(OPT2)" == "$(OPT1)" ]]; then
    echo "data do not match " 1>&2
else
    echo "data matches" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# anyway, in case you simply want to reevaluate until the data is equal this is all you need
# you might want to add a counter maybe to fail after 50 retries or something
while [[ "$(OPT1)" != "$(OPT2)" ]]; do
  echo "data not equal, waiting before retrying"
  sleep 1
done

echo "data match is completed" 

# at this point the data is matched so you can send your email here
```

Comment: Thanks for a really elaborate explanation, Truly appreciate it. However, I just wanted to understand, how the loop will break and proceed.
I must be sounding childish, I am a newbie trying to automate data sync and convert  the database back to its original state.

Comment: well the loop will 'loop' until the condition is fulfilled, so when the data is equal it will simply stop